# Ajustar largura para border de um elemento

Tags: css

Como posso fazer para que a linha em preto não ocupe toda a largura do elemento `tr`? Eu gostaria de diminuir pouca coisa da esquerda mas com `border-width` o comportamento é outro.

```
<tbody>
  <tr class="has-separator">
     <td colspan="2">
        <div class="circle"></div>
            <span>Mês</span>
     </td>
     <td>Nome do curso</td>
     <td>Data do curso</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
     <td></td>
     <td>Nome do curso</td>
     <td>Data do curso</td>
  </tr>

  <tr class="has-separator">
     <td colspan="2">
        <div class="circle"></div>
           <span>Mês</span>
     </td>
     <td>Nome do curso</td>
     <td>Data do curso</td>
  </tr>
  ...
```

O CSS:

```
table tbody tr:not(:first-child)[class="has-separator"] {
    border-top: 1px solid black;
}
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 1):

Tente colocar o CSS assim:

```
table tbody tr:not(:first-child)[class="has-separator"]::after {
    content:" ";
    display: block;
    margin: 0px;
    border-top: 1px solid black;
    background: none;
    width: 100%; /*aqui vc coloca o tamanho que quer que ocupe*/
}
```